# Texas Numeric Hidden Message

Tags: cipher

This [numeric hidden message](http://www.buzzfeed.com/kjh2110/10-logic-puzzles-you-wont-be-able-to-solve) was found on a seat at Rangers Ballpark in Arlington, TX, with an instruction to "Solve the Riddle". What does it mean?

[image: cypher]

Comment: Looks like people have been looking into this for a while:  http://www.reddit.com/r/TexasRangers/comments/1hl06o/can_anyone_help_with_this_xpost_from_rpuzzles/

Comment: I thought the point was to find answers to riddles you couldn't answer.

Comment: @MattMalone , reading the link clearly shows this is not a cipher of any kind, but merely a collection of inside jokes and references.

Comment: @Len I think this is a *different* type of question. Not a challenge by the OP but a *puzzle* he came across. I think it's a valid question here, but the equally suitable answer might be: This is not a puzzle, but a ...

Answer (score 3):

According to the Texas Rangers [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/TexasRangers/comments/1hl06o/can_anyone_help_with_this_xpost_from_rpuzzles/), the numbers correspond to [bits of trivia related to the Texas Rangers](http://www.reddit.com/r/TexasRangers/comments/1hl06o/can_anyone_help_with_this_xpost_from_rpuzzles/cavq6k0). The [owner (it is claimed) confirmed four of the seven sets given](http://www.reddit.com/r/TexasRangers/comments/1hl06o/can_anyone_help_with_this_xpost_from_rpuzzles/cawkigf), which at least also confirms the mechanism.

Comment: You're doing a lot of CW answers lately, xnor...

Comment: @randal'thor Matt Malone pointed out the reddit thread in the comments and the redditors partially solved the problem, so it's not really my answer.