# Solve the riddle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Solve the riddle**,
[image]
**That's all you great folks**
Hint:

> Look for a pattern, then you have it.

Comment: Where did this image come from? Do you know the solution, and if not, are you sure we have all the information we need to solve it?

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for letting me know the reason for downvote(which I have no idea though). There you are. I was having it in my google plus page a long time back, took it from there. regarding your next question yes. I hope it will reveal, if not then it is solution :)

Comment: @L.K. When posting a puzzle to which you yourself do not know the answer, please provide as much context as possible, since it's impossible to know what might be relevant.  e.g. Where did you see this?  What is the green object in the background?  When was this originally seen/posted?  Was there anything else around that may have been a clue to the puzzle?  etc.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain See the edit, if it makes sense. If it is the case with all, then it is better to delete the question.

Comment: Looks like this was posted a few years back.  There's some relevant info in the old question. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/texas-numeric-hidden-message

Comment: @ovaltein It is the same. Superb